# How do I set a picture in powerpoint so that the picture is a clickable hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint

When I want to make a hyperlink behind it the picture is not clickable as a link.
I have to right click and then click open hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2013 (although the process is very similar in previous versions):

1. Insert the image
2. Right-click it, then 'Hyperlink'
3. Enter a web address or select a slide to hyperlink to.